Exponentiating a product of QFT-related operators
Is there a smart way to implement $e^{i\theta\,\Phi\,\rm{QFT} \, \Phi \, \rm{QFT}^\dagger}$, where both $\Phi \propto\sum_j2^jZ_j$ and $\rm{QFT}$ act on the same set of registers? Even an approximate implementation valid for small $\theta$ would be helpful.

Hmm interesting.. if the first $\Phi$ wasn't there you could just do the diagonal $e^{i\Phi}$ conjugated by the $QFT$. Not immediately sure how to deal with that.

Exactly, this is how $\Pi^2$ is traditionally implemented in simulations of quantum field theory, see, e.g., here.

I think this amounts to a $Y$ rotation overall but I’d need to think about it more.

Can you point to the exact equation you are referring to?

It shouldn't be guaranteed that you can do this.
For example lets look at the 1 qubit case $QFT = H, \Phi=Z$. We now have $\Phi QFT \Phi QFT^\dagger = ZHZH = ZX$ which is antihermition. The overall exponent is now Hermitian and the resulting matrix wont be unitary.

Nice observation. Would be interesting to find the conditions for the exponent to be hermetian.

If the exponent is both hermitian and unitary, it should square to identity. Not sure if that is computationally viable for big problems though.
